# For loop does not stop in C++ Arduino

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, arduino

I am coding a flight data recorder, and i am trying to display a number in binary using LEDS, however in the for loop it goes through i =0 to i =3 , as each variable is linked to an LED, but after i is equal to 3, it loops back to 0 and stops my FDR from functioning properly. And ive got no idea how to fix the for loop, any suggestions?

```
for (int i=0; i <= 3; i++) 
    {
    Serial.print("I value:");Serial.print(i);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("guesser"); Serial.print(i+3-2*counter);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("digits");Serial.print(digits[i+3-(2*counter)]);
    Serial.println();
    if (digits[i+3-(2*counter)]==1)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i], HIGH);
      Serial.print("THIS BULB LIT UP:");Serial.print(i);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i], LOW);
    }
   counter=counter+1;
   delay(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Is this code in `loop()`? If not, where is it? If so, it's normal that it will be called over and over again.

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

In the Arduino environment, the loop() function is called again and again.